# C++ function returns a valid 'by reference' object after destroy

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, destructor, return-by-reference

I'm using visual studio 2010 compiler and I'm trying to understand the output of this program.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
public:
    int i;
    A()
    {
        i=0; cout<<"constructing A..\n";
    }
    A(int a): i(a)
    {
        cout<<"constructing A with argument\n";
    }
    A(A& a)
    {
        i=a.i;
        cout<<"copy constructor\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout<<"destructing a: " << i << endl;
    }
};

A& f(A b)
{
    return A(25);
}

void main()
{
    A m;
    cout << "i = " << f(m).i << endl;
}
```

**Output:**
constructing A..
copy constructor
constructing A with argument
destructing a: 25
destructing a: 0
i = 25
destructing a: 0

From my understanding, A(25) returned by reference and then destroyed, so why does it print the value of i: 'i = 25'?

Comment: Undefined behavior in your face. Asking about the behavior of undefined behavior is pretty useless.

Comment: If you write something on a piece of paper and throw it in a wastebin, then some minutes later you take a look and the note is still there. Why? Because noone emptied your wastebin in the meantime. You better didnt have anything important on that piece of paper, because if you look later anything could be on it. Someone could have replaced it with something different. Trying to understand undefined behaviour is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior. Nevertheless the output can be as you expected because the memory occupied by the non alive object can be not overwritten yet.